# Elastic Search sort numbers in string

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

In elastic search I am using `sort` to sort by first line of address. However where the address begins with a number it is sorted as:

```
1 Some Street
10 Some Street
12 Some Street
2 Some Street
22 Some Street
24 Some Street
```

I would prefer to order it as 1, 2, 10, 12, 22, 24 etc.

Sort code below in php:

```
$params['sort'] = array('line_1:asc');
```

Comment: Check out [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: Cool, I was looking for a solution in elastic search, but as I'm only returning a small subset of documents in elastic search, sorting in php is fine. The results are in a multi-dimensional array though so I'm going to post the code as an answer.

Comment: Sorting on PHP client side wont work. Mostly you would be working with a page of document at a time ( Say 10 ) and this sort would be only applied on that. But then you need to apply this on the entire documents.

Comment: @VineethMohan The phrase "Sorting on PHP client side" makes me think you don't understand how PHP works... PHP is **strictly** server-side.

Comment: But can it run from inside Elasticsearch "server" ? Lets say we have 1 billion address. It might be impossible to take this entire 1 billion address to PHP side for each search request , sort it based on the above function and take the top 10 or 20 results.... In this case we will need to run it from Elasticsearch "server" side , using the code i have given in the answer section.

Comment: First of all, if your trying to alphanumerically sort a billion items you are wasting way too many resources. try and narrow it down to the 1000 or so most relevant items first then sort them for pagination. As for "what can PHP do with data" the answer is anything given that it takes less than the 30 second timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Function to do a natural sort in a multi-dimensional array:

```
function nat_multi_sort ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['line_1'], $b['line_1']);
}

usort($array, 'nat_multi_sort');
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be solved using [scripting](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting).
If the first token in address is a number , use that number alone for sorting.
Or else pass positive infinity as the sort value.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "try { Integer.parseInt(doc['address'].value); } catch(Exception e){ return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This way , the address which wont start with a number would be sent to the end. And those with a number would be sorted based on its numeric value