# Need to Sort the _term in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Indexer and which contains a field named 'billingSequence'. The datatype for the field in mapping is String and the value for each record for this field can be one among 1 to 30. I am using this field in terms aggregation
and when I tried to sort the _terms, the ordering is improper as the field is of String type.

```
{
      "aggs": {
                    "count": { 
                        "terms": { 
                            "field": "billingSequence"
                            , "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
                         }
                    }
                }

            }
```

the result for the above aggregation sorting is like --
    1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 3 4 5 etc.

the expected result is -- 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 etc.

It would be a great help if someone can look into this and help.

Thanks..

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27683421/1679537) can help you.

Comment: Why not map `billingSequence` as an integer then?

Comment: There is no option to change the mapping. Is there any way to typecast the result field (like _term in this case). :)

Comment: There is no Groovy support is enabled for my project :).  @X.L.Ant

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @X.L.Ant

Comment: Hi Val, Suddenly the elastic search query you gave stopped working. I tried to debug the issue and found that "as Integer" in the script is not working in my ES. Can you please look into this and find me a solution for that. @Val

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're sorting strings and the lexical order of string is different than the order of the numbers represented by those strings.

For strings: "11" comes **before** "2" because "1" is before "2"

For numbers: 11 comes **after** 2 obviously.

The solution to this is to map your `billingSequence` field as an integer instead of a string.

```
{
    "billingSequence": {
        "type": "integer"
    }
}
```

Note that you need to wipe your index first (1), re-create it and install the above mapping (2) and finally re-index your data (3). Then your aggregation will work as expected.

**(1)**

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/your_index
```

**(2)**

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "your_type": {
            "properties": {
                "billingSequence": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**(3)**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/1 -d '{"billingSequence": 1}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/2 -d '{"billingSequence": 2}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/3 -d '{"billingSequence": 3}'
```

**UPDATE**

If changing the mapping is **not an option**, you can use a `script` in your `terms` aggregation to transform your string terms to numbers along with an undocumented feature of the `terms` aggregation, i.e. the `value_type` setting, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc.billingSequence.value as Integer",  <--- transform the terms to integers
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "value_type": "integer",      <--- consider the terms as integer when sorting
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here the situation is like, I am not authorized to change the mappings of the Index. So, is there any way to typecast the result of an aggregation (in this case _term). @Val

Comment: Hi Val, Suddenly the elastic search query you gave stopped working. I tried to debug the issue and found that "as Integer" in the script is not working in my ES. Can you please look into this and find me a solution for that.  @Val

Comment: Have you upgraded your ES recently? I suggest you create a new question by referencing this one, so we're not creating too much noise.

Comment: Yeah Val, we have upgraded our Es. Can you please look into the below link. I have created a new question.                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342142/need-to-sort-the-term-in-elastic-search-aggregation-result                                                   @Val