# Need to Sort the _term in elastic search aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch

[Need to Sort the _term in elastic search aggregation result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969369/need-to-sort-the-term-in-elastic-search)

As per the above question, my elastic search query with the script given by the Val worked fine till the last week. We have upgraded the ES version and suddenly it stopped working.

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"count": {
  "terms": {
    "script": "doc.billingSequence.value as Integer",  <--- transform the terms to integers
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    },
    "value_type": "integer",      <--- consider the terms as integer when sorting
    "size": 10
  }
}
}
}
```

Now suddenly my ES stopped working with code containing "as Integer" in script. Can anyone please check and help.

```
[DEBUG] 2015-10-26 10:00:13,907 org.elasticsearch.action.search.type - [Eson the Searcher] [owce_assets][4], node[aNnn7tvHRi6tCkOA-RU2nw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@123872f5] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [owce_assets][4]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"aggregations_binary":"ewoJCQkJCQkiY291bnQiOiB7IAoJCQkJCQkJInRlcm1zIjogewoJCQkJCQkJCSJzY3JpcHQiOiJkb2MuYmlsbGluZ1NlcXVlbmNlLnZhbHVlIGFzIEludGVnZXIiLAoJCQkJCQkJCSJvcmRlciI6IHsKCQkJCQkJCQkgICJfdGVybSI6ICJhc2MiCgkJCQkJCQkJfSwKCQkJCQkJCQkidmFsdWVfdHlwZSI6ICJpbnRlZ2VyIiwgICAgIAoJCQkJCQkic2l6ZSI6IDIwCgkJCQkJCQkJCgkJCQkJCQkgfQoJCQkJCQl9CgkJCQkJfQ=="}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:634)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:507)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:480)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:252)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: [Error: unknown class or illegal statement: org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2.ParserContext@7915fb96]
[Near : {... doc.billingSequence.value as Integer ....}]
                                         ^
```

I have tried the given query and now it throws the below exception.

```
[DEBUG] 2015-10-26 10:33:01,912 org.elasticsearch.action.search.type - [Eson the Searcher] [owce_assets][4], node[aNnn7tvHRi6tCkOA-RU2nw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@66accd25] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [owce_assets][4]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"aggregations_binary":"ewoiY291bnQiOiB7CiAgInRlcm1zIjogewogICAgInNjcmlwdCI6ICJkb2MuYmlsbGluZ1NlcXVlbmNlLnZhbHVlIGFzIEludGVnZXIiLAogICAgIm9yZGVyIjogewogICAgICAiX3Rlcm0iOiAiYXNjIgogICAgfSwKICAgICJ2YWx1ZV90eXBlIjogImludGVnZXIiLAogICAgInNpemUiOiAxMCwKICAgICJsYW5nIjogImdyb292eSIgICAgICAgICAgICAKICB9Cn0KfQ=="}]]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:634)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:507)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:480)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:252)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:143)
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.search(ScriptService.java:163)
at
org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.TermsParser.parse(TermsParser.java:202)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:114)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:77)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationParseElement.parse(AggregationParseElement.java:60)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBinaryParseElement.parse(AggregationBinaryParseElement.java:42)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:622)
... 11 more
```

The query I am passing as a parameter is::

```
{
    "count": { 
        "terms": {
            "script": "Integer.parseInt(doc.billingSequence.value)",
                "order": {
                              "_term": "asc"
                            },
                              "value_type": "integer",
                            "size": 20

                         }
                    }
                }
```

As my indexer contains 1, 2, 4, 6, 14 values in the `billingSequence` field. But after executing this query, I am getting 2, 4, 6 only in the result.

Exactly my code goes like below..

```
<mix:variable name="aggregations" as="xs:string">
   <mix:option name="disable-expression-parsing" value="true"/>
       {
            "fatal_errors": {
                "filter": { 
                    "and":[
                        <!-- Filter by date (if given). Value should be send as "`DATE#" and the period should be in Filter data(<Filter name="field_name" value="`DATE#">1d</Filter>).-->
                        <mix:for-each select="//Date">
                            <mix:if test="$comma">,</mix:if>
                                { "range": {
                                    "<mix:value-of select='./@name'/>": {
                                        "gte": "now-<mix:value-of select='./@value'/>",
                                            "lt": "now"
                                        }
                                    }
                                 }
                            <mix:global-variable name="comma" select="true()" as="xs:boolean"/>
                         </mix:for-each>    

                        <!-- Filter all the not nulls or blanks in a field (if given). Value should be send as "`NOT_NULL#" (<Filter name="field_name" value="`NOT_NULL#"></Filter>).-->
                        <mix:for-each select="//NotNull">
                            <mix:if test="$comma">,</mix:if>
                                {
                                    "not":
                                        {
                                            "term":{
                                                "<mix:value-of select='./@name'/>":""
                                            }
                                     }
                                }
                            <mix:global-variable name="comma" select="true()" as="xs:boolean"/>
                        </mix:for-each>                                                 

                        <mix:for-each select="//FitlerTerm">
                            <mix:if test="$comma">,</mix:if>
                                {
                                    "term":{
                                        "<mix:value-of select='./@name'/>":"<mix:value-of select='./@value'/>"
                                    }
                                }
                            <mix:global-variable name="comma" select="true()" as="xs:boolean"/>
                        </mix:for-each> 
                    ]
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "count": { 
                        "terms": {
                            "script": "Integer.parseInt(doc.billingSequence.value)",
                            "order": {
                              "_term": "asc"
                            },
                              "value_type": "integer",
                            "size": 20

                         }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        <mix:option name="disable-expression-parsing" value="false"/>
</mix:variable>
```

Here I am passing an aggregation with filter.. My filter is working fine and at the place of aggregation I am getting the issue. Please check and do the needful.

Comment: What version have you updated to? In your new ES install, can you make sure that [scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)?

Comment: Yeah scripting is enabled and the version we are using is 1.7.1 @Val

Comment: Do you get any errors in the ES logs or in your client app logs? If yes, please share them in your question.

Comment: Scripting config also changed in 1.6, so please make sure you update your scripting config with the latest properties as depicted in the doc I linked.

Comment: Hi Val, Please see below the error log for the query..

Comment: I have edited my question with error log. Please check the last line.. as it says 'as Integer' as unknown class or illegal statement. @Val

Comment: It seems you're using `mvel` scripting by default, can you set `"lang": "groovy"` and try again?

Comment: Hmmm.. Yeah Val, but the thing is I have no access to change the settings for any environment related scripts. Can you please suggest me with the answer which works with mvel..??

Comment: Can't you add that directly in your aggregation just after `"size": 10`?

Comment: I am sorry, I can add it in my aggregation. But don't know exactly how it should be added. Can you please help me with it..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're using `mvel` scripting. You simply need to specify that you want to use `groovy` instead.

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"count": {
  "terms": {
    "script": "doc.billingSequence.value as Integer",
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    },
    "value_type": "integer",
    "size": 10,
    "lang": "groovy"              <--- add this line
  }
}
}
}
```

Also make sure that you include this to your project dependencies as it's not included by default:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

If you really cannot use Groovy, you can stick to MVEL and use MVEL type casting instead:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"count": {
  "terms": {
    "script": "Integer.parseInt(doc.billingSequence.value)",   <--- change this line
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    },
    "value_type": "integer",
    "size": 10
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it Val, it says "script_lang not supported [groovy]"..  Please refer the edited question for the logs. @Val

Comment: Are you embedding the ES libraries in your application?

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure whether Groovy has it's own jars. I can't see any groovy related jars in my project's libraries directory.

Comment: Yeah Val, the issue may be closed without groovy scripting. As I am working under restricted environment from my client. :)

Comment: Yeah Val, working on it. It is not giving the sorted values. The typecasting might not be applied on it properly it seems. @Val

Comment: Yeah.. Now the query is error free. :) But I wonder, how it accepts 'int' and 'Integer' both.. and without expected output. :)

Comment: Can you try this instead? `"script": "Integer.parseInt(doc.billingSequence.value)"`

Comment: Yeah Val.. I tried it. It gives same results with some missing elements. Like I have 1, 14, 2, 3, 4 6 for the (int) doc.billingSequence.value and now I have only 14, 2, 4, 6 as the answer for the query.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you specify `"value_type": "integer"` in your query? Can you show how you run your query from within your Java app?

Comment: Hi Val.  I use a framework built on Java. What I need to do is just I have to pass the query as a parameter. Please check my updated question for the query I am passing and the result.

Comment: Aren't you missing the `"aggs":{...}` section in your query?

Comment: hmmm... :) as I am using 'aggregations' parameter, by default it adds that section. I need to ignore the parent object. @Val

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear without seeing the actual Java code. Any way to share that?

Comment: Yeah Val, I have updated my question with the code. That might create little ambiguity. I am writing an aggregation with filters. The filters filter the data as required and in the end I am applying terms aggregation on billingSequence. @Val

Comment: Well, then maybe it is possible that your top-level `filter` aggregation that filters out values 1 and 14? But are your buckets sorted properly?

Comment: Hmmmm... Yeah Val. Now it is working fine in my local environment. I wonder, the simple aggregation without filters is filtering 1 and 14 and when I execute the same with filters it gives all the result including 1 and 14. Anyhow, as a whole it's working fine in my local env. Need to post the same into the dev. Will get back to you if any further help required. Thanks for the great help.